# remove files after insertion into tarball

Tags: bash, tar, path, xargs

I want to limit the number of files that get put into a tar ball and erease them after they've been inserted into the tarball and being indipendent from the current directory. I've tried this:
`tar -C ~/semios/tmp/ -cjvf ~/semios/tmp/test.tar.bz2 $(cd ~/semios/tmp/; ls *| head -5) | xargs rm -f` but this leaves the files where they are as the verbose option of `tar` only prints the file name, not the whole path, I thought I could fix it with the `-C` argument but it doesn't look like it... any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no evil chars (whitespace, newlines) in the paths:

```
... $(ls ~/semios/tmp/*| head -5) | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

or

```
... | { cd ~/semios/tmp/; xargs -d '\n' rm -f; }
```

or

```
tar -C ~/semios/tmp/ -cjvf ~/semios/tmp/test.tar.bz2 \
  $(cd ~/semios/tmp/; ls * | head -5 | 
    { while read file; do echo "$file"; rm -f "$file"; done;})
```

**edit**

As `xargs` uses any blanks as delimiters by default, newline should be set as the only delimiter. But due to the `$()` this example would crash even with whitespace in the name.

Answer (score 0):

or

`$ tar -cjf test.tar.bz2 $(find ~/semios/tmp/ -name "*"| head -5 | xargs rm -f)`

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes I have

Comment: That is really strange because if I run something like `$(find ~/semios/tmp/ -name "*"| head -5 | xargs rm -f)` then it expands to nothing.